# Python - Turning a created string into a conversion specifier

Tags: python, string, placeholder

I have a script that creates a random string and I want to turn that in to a placeholder. 
Here's my script:

```
import random

def randstring(length=10):
    valid_letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz1234567890'
    return ''.join((random.choice(valid_letters) for i in xrange(length)))
print randstring(15)
#prints something like "qkxfdqp5jockf6n"
```

I want to be able to turn the created value of "randstring(15)" into a conversion specifier such as %s or %d.
This should be simple but I can't figure it out. 
Thanks.

Comment: "turn the created value of "randstring(15)" into a conversion specifier such as %s or %d" .. not sure I understand, could you possibly rephrase please?

Comment: %d will work only if the random values returned are integers.

Comment: when I run that it spits out a string, qkxfdqp5jockf6n for example. I want to take that be able to do something like print "Hello, %s" and it say "Hello, qkxfdqp5jockf6n"

Comment: You can't define your own conversion specifiers. You can use `%(qkxfdqp5jockf6n)s` with a mapping if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I run that it spits out a string, qkxfdqp5jockf6n for example. I want to take that be able to do something like print "Hello, %s" and it say "Hello, qkxfdqp5jockf6n"

`%s` is not magic, and it doesn't magically know what you want to substitute in. It's a placeholder. You substitute your string into it *the same way you would substitute any other string*:

```
text = 'Damien'
def my_function():
    return 'Damien'

# All of the following will print "Hello, Damien":
print 'Hello, %s' % 'Damien'
print 'Hello, %s' % text
print 'Hello, %s' % my_function()
```

There is no "turning" of anything "into" a conversion specifier.

Comment: I think `'Hello, %s' % text` is what OP was looking for, but +1 for completeness.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I kind of skipped a step while explaining, I know I can't turn things into placeholders etc.. I didn't know you could do this, however: print 'Hello, %s' % my_function()

Comment: Even if you didn't know that, did you consider assigning the return value to a variable and then using the variable?

Answer (score 2):

use `format()` instead of old `%s` string formatting.

```
import random

def randstring(length=10):
  valid_letters='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvqxyz1234567890'
  return "hello, {0:s}".format(''.join((random.choice(valid_letters) for i in xrange(length))))
print (randstring(15))
```

**output:**

```
hello, u3gbd0p2rfvrsze
```